# What is "Element" type?

Tags: swift, collections, element

Reading **Swift Programming Language** book I've seen number of references to type `Element`, which is used to define type of collection items. However, I can't find any documentation on it, is it class, protocol? What kind of functionality/methods/properties it has?

```
struct Stack<Element>: Container {
    // original Stack<Element> implementation
    var items = [Element]()
    mutating func push(_ item: Element) {
        items.append(item)
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we tried trace the idea of how we do even get `Element` when working with collections, we would notice that it is related to the *[Iterator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol)* protocol. Let's make it more clear:

[Swift Collection types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) ([Array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array), [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary) and [Set](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set)) are all conforms to [Collection protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection). Therefore, when it comes to the Collection protocol, we can see that the root of it is the [Sequence protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence):

> A type that provides sequential, **iterated** access to its elements.

Sequence has an **Element** and **Iterator** associated types, declared as:

```
associatedtype Element

associatedtype Iterator : IteratorProtocol where Iterator.Element == Element
```

<sub>You could review it on the Sequence [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L325).</sub>

As shown, `Iterator` also has an [**Element** associated type](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L179), which is compared with the sequence Element, well what does that means?

[`IteratorProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol) is the one which does the actual work:

> The IteratorProtocol protocol is tightly linked with the Sequence
>   protocol. Sequences provide access to their elements **by creating an**
>   **iterator, which keeps track of its iteration process and returns one**
>   **element at a time as it advances through the sequence.**

So, Element would be the type of returned element to the sequence.

---

**Coding:**

To make it simple to be understandable, you could implement such a code for simulating the case:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype MyElement
}

extension MyProtocol where MyElement == String {
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}

struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {
    typealias MyElement = String
}

MyStruct().sayHello()
```

Note that -as shown above- implementing an extension to `MyProtocol` makes `MyElement` associated type to be sensible for the where-clause.

Therefore `sayHello()` method would be only available for `MyProtocol` types (`MyStruct` in our case) that assign String to `MyElement`, means that if `MyStruct` has been implemented as:

```
struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {
    typealias MyElement = Int
}
```

you would be *not* able to:

```
MyStruct().sayHello()
```

You should see a compile-time error:

> 'MyStruct.MyElement' (aka 'Int') is not convertible to 'String'

The same logic when it comes to Swift collection types:

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the definition in the [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html) documentation

> Element defines a placeholder name for a type to be provided later.
>   This future type can be referred to as Element anywhere within the
>   structure’s definition.

Comment: But what is special with `Element`? In the example of my original post I could use simply `T` instead of `Element`, right?

Comment: Nothing special about `Element`. It's just a name. Use `T` if you like, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Pablo It is mentioned in the above documentation that T is also a  placeholder, Swift doesn’t look for an actual type called T. So, its up to you what name you want to give. You will see T, U, E etc where multiple generic type are used in same method or structure. So, they are just placeholder names for any type.

Comment: @Gereon `Element` is a defined placeholder, `T` is a made-up placeholder. You cannot always use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 3):

`Element` is usually used as the generic type name for collections, as in

```
public struct Array<Element> { ... }
```

so it is what you construct your array from, and not something predefined by the language.

Comment: So it can be just `T` instead of `Element` or any other name?

Comment: Yes. They could have used `struct Array<T>`. It's just a name Apple have chosen.

Answer (score 2):

`Element` is a purpose-built (and defined) placeholder for structures. **Unlike some of the answers/comments have suggested, `Element` cannot always be substituted for `T`** because `T` without the proper context is undefined. For example, the following would not compile:

```
infix operator ++

extension Array {
    static func ++ (left: Array<T>, right: T) -> Array {
        ...
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't know what `T` is, it's just an arbitrary letter—it could be any letter, or even symbol (`T` has just become Swift convention). However, this *will* compile:

```
infix operator ++

extension Array {
    static func ++ (left: Array<Element>, right: Element) -> Array {
        ...
    }
}
```

And it compiles because the compiler knows what `Element` is, a defined placeholder, not a type that was arbitrarily made up.